# Mongoose $push whole array in database

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm having an error on my database where the sub array that I push to my database is missing and created a new id which means it detects data pushed inside.

here's the data I pushed. (toDeliver array has 4 objects inside).
I'm trying to send the whole array along with the string outside of the array.

[image]

after the request here what I receive on my database which is mongoDB.

[image]

the object inside toDeliver array is incomplete and created a ObjectId.
but the string outside of array was save the database.

here's my schema.

```
const OwnerSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        require: true,
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        require: true,
        type: String,
    },
    isAdmin: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    store: [
        {
            product_identifier: {
              type: String,
              require: true,
            },
            productname: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
              },
            price: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
              },
            quantity: {
                type: Number,
                required: true,
              },
            categoryfilter: {
              type: String,
              required: true
            },
            description: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
              },
            specs: {
              type: String,
              required: true
            },
            imageBase64: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
              },
            timestamp: {
              type: String,
              required: true,
            }
            
        }
    ],
    delivery: [
      {
        clientname: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        address: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        }, 
        email: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        number: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
        },
        toDeliver: [
          {
            product_identifier: {
              type: String,
              require: true,
            },
            productname: {
              type: String,
              required: true
            },
            price: {
              type: Number,
              required: true
            },
          }
        ],
        toDeliverPaidViaPaypal: [
          {
            product_identifier: {
              type: String,
              require: true,
            },
            productname: {
              type: String,
              required: true
            },
            price: {
              type: Number,
              required: true
            },
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
});
```

here's my backend.

```
export const delivery = async (req,res) => {

    const { id } = req.params;

    console.log(id);
    console.log(req.body);

    try {
        if(!id) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'ID not found' });
        await OwnerModels.findByIdAndUpdate(id,
            {
                $push: {
                    delivery: 
                    {
                        clientname: req.body.delivery[0].clientname,
                        address: req.body.delivery[0].address,
                        email: req.body.delivery[0].email,
                        number: req.body.delivery[0].number,
                        toDeliver: 
                            [{
                                product_identifier: req.body.delivery[0].toDeliver.product_identifier,
                                productname: req.body.delivery[0].toDeliver.productname,
                                price: req.body.delivery[0].toDeliver.price
                            }]
                        ,
                        toDeliverPaidViaPaypal: []
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                new: true,
            },(err,res)=> {
                if(err) return console.log({ error: err });
                console.log({  result: res.delivery });
            }).clone();
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server error' });
    }
}
```

hope ya guys can help me. thank you

Comment: If your using a mongoose Schema for your model can you post that?

Comment: I jsut posted the schema check it please thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add square brackets around the toDeliver object to make it an array like your console object:

```
$push: {
    delivery: {
        clientname: req.body.delivery[0].clientname,
        address: req.body.delivery[0].address,
        email: req.body.delivery[0].email,
        number: req.body.delivery[0].number,
        toDeliver: [{
            product_identifier: req.body.delivery[0].toDeliver.product_identifier,
            productname: req.body.delivery[0].toDeliver.productname,
            price: req.body.delivery[0].toDeliver.price
        }],
        toDeliverPaidViaPaypal: []
    }
}
```

Also add "_id: false" to toDelivery in your schema to repress id from being generated for the sub-object:

```
    toDeliver: [
      {
        product_identifier: {
          type: String,
          require: true,
        },
        productname: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        price: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
        },
        _id: false,
      }
    ],
```